# Open password protected presentation

Tags: c#, vba, vsto, powerpoint, office-interop

How can I open the password-protected PowerPoint presentation using C# or VBA,in excel `workbook.open` the method has a password parameter. But in PowerPoint, it does not have.

In PowerPoint `Presentation.Open` method does not have a password parameter

In Excel, I can use 
`Application.Workbooks.Open(Filename,Password)` But there is no equivalent in PowerPoint

I need to pass the password during PowerPoint document open

Comment: Try using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.presentation.password

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This will Work:** ***Tested in VBA***

```
Dim PVW As ProtectedViewWindow, Pres As Presentation

Set PVW = ProtectedViewWindows.Open("Full Path ", "Password")

Set Pres = PVW.Edit("modify")
```

---

***Another Method: Untested***

```
Sub SetPassword()

    With Presentations.Open(FileName:="C:\My Documents\Earnings.ppt")

        .Password = complexstrPWD 'global variable

        .Save

        .Close

    End With

End Sub
```

Taken From: [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.presentation.password)

Comment: Are the `DoEvents` calls really needed? FWIW the bottom example copied from docs looks like it's *setting* the password; I'd expect PowerPoint to prompt for the password-to-open before `Presentations.Open` returns.

Comment: Yes, Even I thought so, that's why I posted the First one. Which is a tested code. And for the `DoEvents`, Not really needed though. It was there in the code. I ll remove them.